# Retrieve available disk drives

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I've got a function:

```
void get_disk_drives() {
  DWORD drives_bitmask = GetLogicalDrives();

  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (((drives_bitmask >> i) & 1)) {
      char drive_name = (char)(65 + i);
      cout << drive_name << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
A
C
D
W
X
Y
Z
```

But my system (Windows 8 in Parallels on Mac OS X) shows me, that available disk drives is:

```
C
W 
X
Y
Z
```

[image]

What's wrong?

---

**UPD:**

I haven't floppy and CD/DVD in MacBook Air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this means that drives `A` and `D` exist, but have no media in them. My guess is that `A` is a legacy floppy drive, and `D` is an optical drive (CD/DVD).

You could call `GetDriveType` to find out more.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but I haven't floppy and CD/DVD on Mac

Comment: They are probably virtualized by Parallels. Why don't you ask the machine?

Comment: `GetLogicalDrives()` (and `GetLogicalDriveStrings()`) does not care if there is media in a drive or not. As long as the drive itself exists and has a drive letter assigned to it, it will be reported. So if `GetLogicalDrives()` is reporting drives `A` and `D` then they really do exist as far as Windows is concerned. You can verify that with Windows' Disk Manager (My Computer > Manage > Storage > Disk Management), or just by looking in Windows Explorer. Like David said, Parallels is likely providing virtual devices for `A` and `D`, if they do not physically exist on the Mac host.